# faster redis lookup for collection of keys

Tags: redis

i'm looking for a faster way to lookup a collection of keys in redis.

that's what i need to do:

```
HGET "user:001:coins" "2013-05-01"
```

it looks up stored coins for a user on a specific day.

Now i want to lookup all stored coins for a date range of a month:

```
HGET "user:001:coins" "2013-05-01"
HGET "user:001:coins" "2013-05-02"
....
```

Thats getting slow becasue i have to do that for 120 different users over 2 months. Is there a faster/better way to do this ?

one idea i had would be to add another key which holds the calculated coins amount for a month, and always recalculate the key if there is a change.

```
HGET "user:001:coins" "2013-05"
```

but that would mean additional programming logic, which i would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructuring your data is not a bad idea even if it does require additional work. Fetching once is always faster than fetching N times.

If you can group your operations together, why not use [HMGET](http://redis.io/commands/hmget)?

```
HMGET "user:001:coins" "2013-05-01" "2013-05-02" ...
```

Comment: awesome, with hmget i do not need to think about restructuring anymore. thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: The [Redis documentation](http://redis.io/) is exceptional. You should spend some time reading it as there's a lot of useful tools in there.

Comment: this of course works if you know your hash keys (members) in advance.

Comment: You'll need to know the keys you're fetching if you're using multiple `HGET` calls as in the original question.